# SQL Server Date Conversion from .NET DateTime.Now.ToString

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

We have a legacy system written in .NET which inserts a simple DateTime into SQL Server (as a string field).  Something like below:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dateSent", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
```

This results in a string like below in the SQL Server database:

```
9/6/2016 3:00:15 AM
```

I'm simply trying to run some queries in SQL Server and convert this format to a date.  For example, sorting by below:

```
order by CONVERT(DATE, DateSent)
```

Will get the proper date, but the time format doesn't sort properly.  I've tried a few SQL Server formats [example link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) but these don't seem to work.

I must be missing something obvious?  I would have assumed the default .NET DateTime would very easily convert in SQL Server.

Comment: How are you able to add a parameter to `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: If it's not sorting properly, maybe you just need to set proper date style.

Comment: Pass a date instead of a string and many problems will disappear

Comment: @techspider - the parameters were on the .NET code that inserts the date strings.  The ORDER BY was part of a normal SQL query that I'm executing on this data that .NET is inserting.

Comment: @OctoCode - That's exactly what I was thinking too.  I tried a bunch of style options from the link in my post.  I'm a little surprised that SQL Server doesn't grab the right time even when converting to a date, but I suppose the time isn't part of that data type.

Comment: @Plutonix - Agreed - if I could change this legacy code to just use date formats I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.  I somehow missed this for the past hour of looking.  It was obvious, but here it is in case someone else stumbles into this.

I don't know SQL Server data types well (obviously).  Using DateTime on that side fixed this issue.

```
order by CONVERT(DATETIME, DateSent)
```